# Jquery improve structure of my plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm trying to make my first jquery plugin and would like to know if the structure I made is correct and if you have suggestions to improve it.

```
;(function ($, window, document, undefined) {

    // Function-level strict mode syntax
    'use strict';

    var foo = null;
    var bar = {};

    function init(options) {
        myFunc1(options);
        myFunc2(options);
    };

    function myFun1(opts) {
        foo = 'hallo',
        bar = { one : 1, two : 2}
    };

    function myFun2(opts) {
        getGlobals();
        //do other
    };

    function getGlobals() {
        var params = {
            getFoo : foo,
            getBar : bar
        }
        return params;
    };

    $.fn.myPlugin = function(options) {

        var options = $.extend({}, $.fn.myPlugin.defaults, options);

        return this.each(function() {

            init(options);

            var $this = $(this);

            $this.on('click', 'div', function() {
                myFunc2(options);
            });
        };
    });

    $.fn.myPlugin.defaults = {
        cssIconUp : 'glyphicon-chevron-up',
        cssIconDown : 'glyphicon-chevron-down'
    };

})(jQuery, window, document);
```

My doubts concern the initialization mode (init) , access to options by the functions and set globals vars. It can be done differently and in a better way?
Thank you

Comment: Possibly better for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Liam I don't think this would fit on CodeReview, since it still has some example code in it. `myFun1` and `myFun2` will most likely trigger a close-vote for the same reason. Not to mention the `foo`, `bar`, `getFoo`, `getBar` and `myPlugin`.

Comment: @Liam Yup, this is definetivelly example code. CodeReview only works with **real** code, and example code is off-topic.

Comment: OP's real code would be delightedly received at CR though.

Comment: Before making real code I would like to know if my structure is correct. What do you say?